# std::array::at not treated as constexpr when using g++ with llvm libcxx

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, clang++

```
typedef std::array<T, 3> C;
constexpr C c = {1, 2, 3.5};
constexpr T t1 = c.at(0);`
```

The third line gives me an error when compiled with `g++`. It works fine with `clang++` when LLVM libc++ is used. It seems like return of `c.at(0)` is not a constexpr using C++ 14. However, `std::array::at` is of the same return type as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at).

This is complete error message:

```
constexpr const value_type& std::__1::array<_Tp, 
_Size>::at(std::__1::array<_Tp, _Size>::size_type) const [with _Tp = 
double; long unsigned int _Size = 3ul; std::__1::array<_Tp, 
_Size>::const_reference = const double&; std::__1::array<_Tp, 
_Size>::value_type = double; std::__1::array<_Tp, _Size>::size_type = long 
unsigned int]’
```

called in a constant expression

```
constexpr T t1 = c.at(0);
```

Comment: Works with GCC here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c531fe7418a3b9e2 . Try upgrading your tool-chain

Comment: Issue is while using the llvm libcxx library. Forgot to mention it earlier